# titlespacing command does not seem to modify spacing after section title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I'm trying to make my own custom section title spacing using the `titlespacing` command in the `titlesec` package. I devised the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\leftspacing}{0pt}
\newcommand{\beforespacing}{0pt}
\newcommand{\afterspacing}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{\leftspacing}{\beforespacing}{\afterspacing}

\begin{document}
  \section*{First Section}
  \section*{Second Section}
  \section*{Third Section}
  \section*{Fourth Section}
\end{document}
```

It turns out that modifying `\leftspacing` and `\beforespacing` visibly modifies the spacing between the sections in the rendered PDF, but `\afterspacing` does not. How can I have full control over the spacing after my sections?

Comment: Any additional information I can provide to make this question more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\afterspacing` = 50pt.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\leftspacing}{0pt}
\newcommand{\beforespacing}{0pt}
\newcommand{\afterspacing}{50pt}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\titlespacing{\section}{\leftspacing}{\beforespacing}{\afterspacing}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section*{First Section}
    \kant[1]
    \section*{Second Section}
    \section*{Third Section}
    \section*{Fourth Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `titlesec` manual states that "By default, when there are two consecutive titles the `<after-sep>` space from the first one is used between them." That's why when you added text it worked OK. Answer accepted.